# Android One CheckBox Selected at a time issue

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a list with items that have checkBox, and I need that only one checkBox to be selected at a time. I cannot use listView with singleChoice nor RadioButtons. Below is my code I am using but I do not know why is not working.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (selectedCheckBox != null) {
        // simulate radio group behavior
        selectedCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        selectedCheckBox = null;
    }

    if (isChecked) {
        selectedCheckBox = (CheckBox) buttonView;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the checkBoxes still remain checked and I do not know why regarding that I set the previous selectedCheckBox to false. Could anyone explain what happens? Thanks

UPDATE
I tested on a Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 and it works on that. On Android versions < 5.0 seems to have the problem I mentioned.

Comment: You must use RadioButtons

Comment: It's not a must. I used checkBoxes to achieve this behavior before by using onClick() listener instead of onCheckChanged(), but I never understood why onCheckChanged() is not working. And I would be grateful if anyone could explain what happens behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call: notifyDataSetChanged() of your ListView Adapter. If not your data in your ListView is not going to refresh and your checkboxes will remain selected.

Comment: Thanks, it works if I call notifyDataSetChanged(). I don't why I didn't think of it. It makes sense now, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have one checkbox in each ListView item, you must loop the entire "other" (that must be unchecked) items, and uncheck it. It's not a practical approach.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a Arraylist to fill Listview. In array list there must be objects like boolean fields. So when a checkbox is checked or unchecked it means that the boolean field is changed to false or true, and then the list view is reproduced. If you follow this way, then it must be easy, first loop through Arraylist and change all booleans to false, then change the selected one to true, that is all, then android will refresh view for you. Hope it help.